# Why Return Type Is Changing in tap() operator Rxjs?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

Why does `tap` operator change the type of `someVar`?

By definition it should not.

This changes the type:

```
somevar = someObs$.pipe(
  tap(console.log)
)
```

This does not:

```
somevar = someObs$.pipe(
  tap((v) => console.log(v))
)
```

Comment: Which type is it being changed to ? What is the source type ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `tap` is a **side effect** operator.

This operator, as the source code comment stats it:

> Used when you want to affect outside state with a notification without
> altering the notification

It does not transform your emitted value but actually lets you receive the value and do something with it **outside** of your observable flow.

In the meanwhile you can do whatever you want to do with your Observable flow and this should not interfere your side effect.

Also. notice that `someVar` will be an `Observable` since you are not subscribing to your `someObs$` observable but actually pipes to it extra operators which do some operations and then wraps the output as Observable and returns that Observable.

A quick example would be to perform a loader indication to the user while you are still not done with your source observable.

An example (an incomplete one):

```
let isLoading = false;

const somevar$ = someObs$.pipe(
    tap(v => this.isLoading = true), 
    filter(someFilter), 
    map(maybeSomeMapping))

somevar$.subscribe(finalValue => {
// maybe some extra code that you can actually write inside the same `tap` or even another `tap` which is more deep in the pipe chain.
this.isLoading = false; // resets the loader.
});
```

One question you may ask is **why?**. Why would I need a `tap` operator if I can simply do the exact same side effect assignments inside a mapper operator (e.g: `map`, `mergeMap`, etc...).

Simply because you will break the pureness of the mapping.

You want each operator to do what it was intended to do.

A `map` should have mapping logic and not interfere with anything else. Keep your functions pure as possible. In case you need some impurness, `tap` is your friend.