# rxjs - why is tap() disrupting the downstream type assertion?

Tags: angular, rxjs, apollo

This is a relatively new observation, so unsure if it's a 'new version' issue.

I seem to be losing type assertion when `tap()` is used early in the pipe. Given that tap is a side effect, I am not expecting it to affect the downstream type assertions like `map` would for example. This now stops me being able to handle side effect logic outside of map.

Take the below example:

```
$query$ = this.bookService.fetch().valueChanges.pipe(
    tap((r) => console.log(r.loading) /** r has correct observable assertion */),
    map(r => {
        // r is now a generic type A. Type assertion lost
    })
)
```

The same behaviour also happens for `takeUntil()` and `takeUntilDestroyed()`.

For example, this also loses type projection and reverts to a generic type:

```
.pipe(
    takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef),
    tap((r) => console.log(r.data.submissionBatches)),
)
```

[image: screenshot]

The observables utilised here are from `angular-apollo` graphql query responses. For example, `Observable<GetBookQuery>`.

So, what am I doing wrong here (if I am), and why am I losing type assertion.

For clarity, this isn't a duplicate question of [Why Return Type Is Changing in tap() operator Rxjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66293418/2476046)
Unlike in that question, the implementation above is to the spec of the rxjs docs, so I am trying to identify why the assertion is being lost.

According to the docs, the tap function should:

> Used when you want to affect outside state with a notification without altering the notification

Versions:

- Rxjs `~7.8.1`
- Angular `~16.1`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Return Type Is Changing in tap() operator Rxjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66293418/why-return-type-is-changing-in-tap-operator-rxjs)

Comment: Already read it, doesn't apply. The asker implemented the tap function incorrectly. In the answer, they do also state that the behaviour should be what I am expecting it to be here, but am not getting. "Used when you want to affect outside state with a notification without altering the notification"

Comment: @Roy also, maybe read the question before you vote to close it 

Comment: Can you provide some stackblitz?

Comment: I've seen the same issue when using just `tap(console.log)` but if I use it as `tap(() => console.log('abc'))` it's fine

Comment: @martin Yeah, me too... I've seen this before, but I am using the correct method `(r) => console.log(r)`. Tbh, I am now at invalidating my IDE caches and trying to identify a source. My type assertions are being disrupted after any pipe, not just a tap, even a simple `take(1)`

Answer (score 1):

APOLOGIES COMMUNITY - **Solved**

Yes, weird type assertions not limited to `tap()`, but also for `takeUntil()`, `take()`... anything tbf that shouldn't alter the notification.

Anyway, no issues with the code or the library versions. All full IDE (WebStorm) cache invalidation and restart/reindex resolved my problems.

Any future readers using the correct code syntax, try flushing out your IDE first.